# Is it possible to restore database without Filestream

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I have actually a small Production Filestream enabled database. Data (150 Mo) + Filestream (500 Mo).

Tomorow, the filestream will grow until 30 Go...

I have many Test Databases that I want to restore with Production dump.

Is it possible to restore production data without Filestream ? Developper don't want blob, image, video...

I can I do ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Back/Restore is for backup/restore, not to give partial data to developers.

Answer (score 0):

[Have look at this question over on DBA.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18315/11567) - it has a couple suggestions for how to work around this type of issue that might be useful to you.  (Basically, you can hide the data with a view, but not leave it out of the restore, as this would leave the database in an inconsistent transactional state.)